# How do I create a task shared by different pools in Bonita Studio?

Tags: bpmn

I'm using Bonita Studio and I would like to create a task which would be shared between two pools and an other shared between two pool lanes.

I'm trying to draw all processes in a web dev company to then optimize them, and a visual support is probably the best way to show the modifications. With this goal in mind I'd need to represent meetings with the different people participating to it.

Am I using the right notation model? If so how do I show these meetings? If not what is a better notation model to show a process with different people working together on different tasks with meetings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In BPMN, pools identify *processes* rather than objects or subjects. You cannot split a single task between two pools.
2. You also cannot split it between two pool lanes. Actually, lanes have no predefined semantics; they can represent anything you want: companies, people, divisions, etc.

So, I'd propose the following. If you have "Software developer", "Designer", "Product Manager" lanes and want all of them participate in a meeting, add one more lane and name it "All project participants". And put the meeting task there.

I think that this won't violate both syntax and semantics of BPMN.

Although you're using Bonita, I'd advise you to visit http://elearning.bizagi.com for a nice online video course dedicated to BPMN diagrams design. It is based on BizAgi modeler, but 1) this modeler is a freeware and 2) There is One BPMN Standard to rule them all. :)

Comment: I know Bizagi but last I've seen it doesn't run on Mac OS

Comment: And on Linux too, so I don't use it often. But the course is great for understanding BPMN standard itself.

Answer (score -1):

Task done by Many persons has no responsibility.
Just decide who is responsible for establishing, facilitating such a meeting and make task "Orgnanize Meeting" in his pool.
You can put note on whom he should invite, checklist, expected outcomes.

Comment: I know the post is old, but that what I figured out today :)