# Multiple roles performing a single task

Tags: bpmn

How can I model a task that is performed by multiple roles?

Example 1: 3 roles have to meet in order to discuss an issue
Example 2: 3 roles collaborate in order to create a concept

-

Comment: So they are different tasks right?

Comment: No, the same task that is collaboratively done by multiple roles (i.e. will be in multiple lanes)

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is thoroughly addressed in this excellent [BPMN blog](https://goodelearning.com/common-bpmn-modeling-mistakes-best-practices-basic-events/):

[image]

Activities **cannot be** placed common neither between pools nor lanes, and this is a common mistake. While this blog proposes possible solution I don't treat it as optimal and recommend you to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19969550/911419) on almost similar question as yours.

In my opinion you have to choose from these two options:

1. Either place your common activity inside separate collaborative lane which will be semantically equal to all your three roles.

[image]

As it fairly stated in the above answer, lane semantics is not strictly described in BPMN standard, so we can freely address any entities through it.

2. Or place [your collaborative activity into separate pool. It's what](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_8.0.4/com.ibm.xtools.bpmn.diagram.doc/topics/c_collab.html) BPMN collaboration diagrams are designated for.

[image]

You should choose the proper variant based on the semantics of your process.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I model a task that is performed by multiple roles?

Example 1: 3 roles have to meet in order to discuss an issue
Example 2: 3 roles collaborate in order to create a concept

Any activity can have only one performer. It is (your question) mean, that 3 roles (performers) do the same activity at the same time and produce "something". 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it is the same task for all users using a multiple instances parallel activity can be a solution.

In this scenario task definition is actually the same for all users: they need to meet other members to discuss an issue or collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

there is a semantical difference in having the same task in separate lane as opposed to having the same task in a unique role lane. The former doesn't highlight a joined effort compared to the later. In other words, 3 people in separate rooms thinking about it, as opposed to 3 people brain-storming together in the same room.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).